# How to detect whether a unicode char is supported in one encoding in ICU?

Tags: c++, unicode, encoding, icu

I need to detect whether a unicode charactere is supported by a specific encoding using ICU. Some code snippet:

```
ucnv_fromUnicode(conv, &targetIndex, targetLimit,
        &source, source + sourceLen, nullptr, flush, &err);
int8_t len = 10;
std::vector<UChar> uchars;
uchars.resize(len);
UErrorCode err = U_ZERO_ERROR;
ucnv_getInvalidUChars(conv, uchars.data(), &len, &err);
if (len != 0) {
    TRACE("unmapable codepoint");
} else {
    TRACE("all green");
}
```

My problem, is this the standard way to do the check or are there any better methods?

I found that the count of invalid uchars could be less than the real one, the len returned would normally be just one. So I began to doubt whether there are better or more stable way to this.

Answer (score 0):

[`ucnv_getUnicodeSet()`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ucnv_8h.html#aec7c273c8ce917ff75224e25914c53be) tells you which codepoints this converter supports. You can use the [`USet`](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/uset_8h.html#adce3fef7c15d7c78196bf977ac96ec9c) API (or `UnicodeSet` in C++) to manipulate, interesect, union etc these sets.